# A call to uphold accessibility by not shortening links to "here"

Tags: discussion, editing, hyperlinks

As far as I see there has been some discussion about the **shortening** of links. While keeping the complete URL visible in the post can clearly be distracting (especially when used inline), I want to warn against making it too drastic (e.g. "here").

Remember that visually handicapped people often use a Screen Reader and should be able to "see" the target of a link without actually selecting it.

So instead of shortening http://htlwz-re01.bplaced.net/wordpress/2013/01/16/problem-no-pub_key-bei-installupdate/ to [here](http://htlwz-re01.bplaced.net/wordpress/2013/01/16/problem-no-pub_key-bei-installupdate/) I suggest [Problem: No pub_key during Install/Update](http://htlwz-re01.bplaced.net/wordpress/2013/01/16/problem-no-pub_key-bei-installupdate/) (at blog.guntbert.net) <sup>1</sup>  or similar.

<sup>1 The link is only provided as an example and has no real relevance here, please don't see it as an advertisement either. I only wanted to make sure to use my own content :-))</sup>

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5873/should-posts-be-edited-to-have-readable-links